# Oracle how to fetch data for todays Date which is saved as Temporal timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have Date field EXECUTION_START in Database table named TRANSACTION.

I save in the table using JPA as,

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)   
private Date EXECUTION_START;
```

The values stored in the DB are in this format "8/18/2020 2:29:08 PM"

How to write a query to fetch the data for today's date ?

```
select * from TRANSACTION where EXECUTION_START = SYSDATE;
select * from TRANSACTION where EXECUTION_START = to_date('08/18/2020','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

**EDIT** - The DB Query as suggested by @Littlefoot works.

```
select * from TRANSACTION where trunc(EXECUTION_START) = trunc(SYSDATE);
```

But when i use it in my **New JPA Query** it fails,

```
@Query("SELECT txn FROM Transaction txn WHERE txn.JOB_NAME = :jobName AND TRUNC(txn.EXECUTION_START) = :TRUNC(SYSDATE) and txn.STATUS = 'RUNNING'")
public Transaction getTransactionByJobName(@Param("jobName") String jobName);
```

Getting the below error,

```
line 1:135: unexpected token: (
line 1:136: unexpected token: SYSDATE
line 1:143: expecting EOF, found ')'
```

I am not getting the proper output with the above queries.

Also ive written my JPA query as below,

```
@Query("SELECT txn FROM TRANSACTION txn WHERE txn.NAME = :name AND txn.EXECUTION_START = :SYSDATE")
public Transaction getTransactionByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `execution_start` column's datatype is `date`, it contains both date and time. Its format is not readable by us, humans - that's why we use `to_char` function and desired format mask to display it as we want.

But, if you're about to select values that depend on that column, then: as `sysdate` is a function which returns `date` datatype (read: both date **and** time, set to "right now" (according to time on the database server), values stored in that column aren't likely to be equal to that value.

What we *usually* do is to "remove" time component by truncating the value; it, actually, sets time to 00:00 at the beginning of that date. It means that something like this might do the job:

```
select * from TRANSACTION where trunc(EXECUTION_START) = trunc(SYSDATE);
```

Note that it won't use index on the `execution_start` column (if it exists); that can be "fixed", but - let's try whether it works at all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Littlefoot . The Query gives the desired output, but i am now stuck with the JPA Query. How to use trunc in JPA Query ??

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know, I don't use JPA.